# c# Changing variable object also changes original

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

As I understood it, when you define a variable with new it uses a new pointer so would be independent of each other.

However, when I execute the following code, the "Selected" property in "apps" also changes to true when I just want "cats" to reinitialize its values from the original "apps" list.

Am I missing something??

```
List<Apps> apps = (from a in db.Categories
                   select new Apps
                   {
                        CategoryId = a.CategoryId,
                        CategoryName = a.CategoryName,
                        Selected = false
                   }).ToList();

foreach (var user in adminUserList)
{
     List<Apps> cats = new List<Apps>(apps);

     cats[0].Selected = true;
}
```

Comment: new object, not new list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becaue they are refferring to the same objects elements of the list though you have a shallow copy of list but the elements of List are still referring to same memory location, you have to create new objects this way:

```
List<Apps> cats = apps.Select(x=>new Apps
                   {
                        CategoryId = x.CategoryId,
                        CategoryName = x.CategoryName,
                        Selected = false
                   }).ToList();
```

Now iterate on cats:

```
foreach (var user in adminUserList)
{

     cats[0].Selected = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  If I place that new declaration for "cats" inside the foreach loop it now works! Thank you.